# end input programmatically in a golang terminal application

Tags: go

I am trying to end terminal input programmatically in 3 seconds and output the result.

My code is the following:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"
)

var (
    result string
    err    error
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Please input something, you have 3000 milliseconds")
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 3000)
        fmt.Println("It's time to break input and read what you have already typed")
        fmt.Println("result")
        fmt.Println(result)
    }()
    in := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    result, err = in.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Please input something, you have 3000 milliseconds
hello It's time to break input and read what you have already typed
result
```

I just printed `hello` and 3 seconds passed and the program should end the input and read my `hello` and give output:

```
result
hello
```

But I don't know how to provide this. Is it possible to end terminal input without user's intention and read the inputted value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't timeout the read on stdin directly, so you need to create a timeout around receiving the result from the reading goroutine:

```
func getInput(input chan string) {
    in := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    result, err := in.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    input <- result
}

func main() {
    input := make(chan string, 1)
    go getInput(input)

    select {
    case i := <-input:
        fmt.Println(i)
    case <-time.After(3000 * time.Millisecond):
        fmt.Println("timed out")
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, `getInput` will consume a line from stdin whether `main` is still waiting for it or not. If this were reused, the line would be lost. Can this be avoided, with a true timeout after which the read is aborted?

Comment: @slezica: there is no such thing as a "true timeout", so you cannot abort the read (that's what the question is asking). It's correct that you cannot reuse this function, because it's a simple example that's not designed to be reused. Of course there are many other ways to return multiple lines without losing data.

Comment: I would love to know how. Would you be so kind as to point me in the right direction? I need to read 2 pieces of input, each with a timeout, and everything I managed to google has the same problem: with unlucky timing, a line will be lost in the abandoned goroutine.

Comment: Just make one goroutine that continually returns tokens from the input. It's not really appropriate to try and format into a a comment. If you're having trouble I suggest filing a new question.

Comment: No need, I understood perfectly. Sorry for the back and forth.